# email validation from csv file in java

Tags: java, email, csv, indexoutofboundsexception, opencsv

So I have this CSV file that contains a bunch of fields, and one of which is an email field. Some of the emails that have been input are empty and others are incorrect format. Kind of like this:

```
Entry|First Name|Last Name|Email|Sign-up Date
1|Mike|Smith|mike.smith@gmail.com|2004-08-08
2||||2006-06-12
3|Perry|File|public|2010-09-14
```

My code here to detect that the email is valid is as so:

```
private boolean[] validEmail;

public void setValidEmail(File fileName){
    Log log = LogFactory.getLog(LoadValidEmail.class);
    try{
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName.getPath()));
        String[] row = null;
        char[] email = null;
        int count = 0;
        while(!(row = csvReader.readNext()).equals(null)){
            if(count!=0){
                if(!row[3].isEmpty()){
                    email = row[3].toCharArray();
                    for(int i = 0; i < email.length; i++){
                        if(email[i] == '@'){
                            validEmail[count-1]=true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!validEmail[count-1]){
                        validEmail[count-1] = false;
                    }
                }else{
                    validEmail[count-1] = false;
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        log.info("File could not be found, make sure directory is correct and try again");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        log.info("File could not read next line, make sure file contains information and try again");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        log.info("The array has gone out of bounds, this is not the row you are looking for");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Every time it runs it throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException and crashes right at the line:

```
if(!row[3].isEmpty()){
    ...
}
```

I don't really know why it's throwing this error, as I am trying to access the email field, which is the fourth field of the CSV file. Why is it throwing this Exception and how would I fix it to not automatically throw it?

Comment: First thing, you need to tell `CSVReader` that your separater is `|` by default, it takes `,` `new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName.getPath()), '|');`.

Comment: When you do System.out.println(row.length) what do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you need to tell CSVReader that your separater is `|` by default, it takes `,` something like `new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName.getPath()), '|');`.

Also, I don't see any reason to have `validEmail` as an array, I think it should be just a `boolean`.

One more suggestion is to use regex to validate email rather than reading it char by char and validate.